# Javascript: how to get a blob from binary data (Not from an XHR)

Tags: javascript, blob

There are a number of questions relating to turning binary into a blob, but all the answers so far bypass the question and assume you can get the Blob directly from the XHR or fetch or other net query.

In my case this isn't the case, I have a PDF binary, (coming from one of a number of sources) but all the obvious ways to turn it into a Blob fail. In most cases the resulting file is 450k, rather than the 260K in the original data, which suggests a Unicode conversion.

```js
foo = '%PDF ....'
b = new Blob([foo], {type: "application/pdf"})
u = URL.createObject(b)
```

Note there are answers for doing this with Base64 data, but this is a straightforward binary string.

Comment: Normally, your  text editor won't allow you to insert raw binary data in a js source file. So yes, the most possible case is your pdf being silently converted to utf8 or like that.

Comment: Sorry, that code was illustrative, the text is being retrieved from a distributed network and turns up as a binary string, which is what I want to keep it as when I pass it on to URL.createObject()